# Euler-Lagrange equation with a damping term

Tags: differential-equations, variational-calculus

We know that there is a function [`` VariationalMethods`EulerEquations ``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/ref/EulerEquations.html) readily handling the Euler-Lagrange equation of the "standard" form

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} - \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\right) = 0.
$$

But today, it suddenly occurs to me that problems [e.g., see Eqs. (5) & (6) in this [note](http://www.physics.hmc.edu/%7Esaeta/courses/p111/uploads/Y2013/lec131023-DSHO.pdf)] with a damping term are not included, are they?

My question is, is there any hidden magic in `` VariationalMethods`EulerEquations `` that makes it still capable of dealing with equations like

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} - \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\right) - \frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot q} = 0, \qquad F = \frac{b}{2}\dot q^2,
$$

or one has to return to manual establishment of equations of motion using functions like `D` or `` VariationalMethods`VariationalD ``?

Comment: Generalized forces $Q_x$ are not part of Euler-Lagrangian, and have to be added separately, as in $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = Q_x$. So one has to know what $Q_x$ in this case is, from the physics of the problem, such as friction, etc... and add these to the RHS of the equations. I have not used this package myself btw.

Comment: @Nasser Thx. Do you mean to manually replace the `0` on the RHS with the generalized force?

Comment: Yes. That is what is done when doing these by hand. First find the Euler-Lagrange equations, then check the physics and see if there are forces not included (these are the so called generalized forces, non-conservative, or whatever you prefer to call them). Such as friction, damping, etc... and make sure to include the ones related to each coordinate in question $x_i$, to the RHS. Now you have the complete equations of motion. I solved many problems like these, but by hand, and did not use this package. These are fun problems to work out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. First of all I recommend you to read these two papers:

1. J. Guerrero, F. F. López-Ruiz, V. Aldaya, and F. Cossio *[A round trip from Caldirola to Bateman systems](https://doi.org/10.1088/1742-6596/284/1/012062)*, J. Phys.: Conf. Ser. **284**, 012062 (2011)
2. H. Dekker, *[Classical and quantum mechanics of the damped harmonic oscillator](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(81)90033-8)*, Phys. Rep. **80**, 1-110 (1981)

There are basically two ways to deal with dissipation (damping) in the Lagrangian formalism of classical mechanics:

1. The Bateman method,
2. The Caldirola-Kanai method.

They can also be used in order to quantize the classical equations of motion. As an example, consider a harmonic oscillator with frequency $ \Omega $ and damping $ \lambda $, where we set the mass to be equal to 1.

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

BatemanL = x'[t] y'[t] - Ω^2 x[t] y[t] + λ (x[t] y'[t] - x'[t] y[t]);

EulerEquations[BatemanL, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
(*{-Ω^2 y[t] + 2 λ y′[t] - y′′[t] == 0, -Ω^2 x[t] - 2 λ x′[t] - x′′[t] == 0*)

CaldirolaKanaiL = Exp[λ t] (1/2 x'[t]^2 - 1/2 Ω^2 x[t]^2)

EulerEquations[CaldirolaKanaiL, x[t], t]
(*-E^(t λ) (Ω^2 x[t] + λ x′[t] + x′′[t]) == 0*)
```

The idea of the *Bateman*'s method is to introduce an auxiliary coupled system $ y(t) $ that evolves in negative time-direction (notice a sign difference in the equation of motion for $ y(t) $ as compared to $ x(t) $), so that in total the energy is conserved.

The idea of *Caldirola-Kanai* is in introducing the time-dependence into the Lagrangian explicitly. It is worth noting that these two methods can be generalized to more complicated scenarios.

Comment: Looks great! Thx a lot for the answer. Let me spend some time digesting.